# Why do I always sneeze and get watery eyes when I pluck my eyebrows? Is it a reflex/trigger? Nerves linked?

Tags: reflex-impulse, sneeze-sneezing, watery-eyes, pluck-plucking, eyebrows

Why do I always sneeze and get watery-eyes when I pluck my eyebrows? Is it a reflex?

Are the nerves around our eyebrows linked to our nasal cavity?